# Logitech G Hub LUA script for slow down scroll speed

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I own a G604 mice and I need to change the rows scroll only for Excel and Calc. I found in another thread a script that allows scrolling with keys, not exactly what I'm looking for but the biggest problem is that it scrolls 3 lines at a time since Windows has this setting.

This is the script I'm testing:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
         MoveMouseWheel(1)
         Sleep(50)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

How can I change the parameter MoveMouseWheel so that it scrolls only 1/3?

Comment: GHub can not choose the amount of lines per single wheel move, GHub can only emit a mouse wheel event.  It is an OS settings (or Excel settings) to determine how many lines to scroll.